# How to customize UI display of an ItemFeed in the Chatter Feed?

Tags: chatter, feeditem, page-layout

I'm trying to customize the way Chatter displays items in the Chatter Feed but I'm not sure it's even possible.

By default, it seem that SF is using his own rendering method depending on FeedItem type :

- Links are parsed and preview metadata are embeded for whitelisted domains (Youtube, Vidyard, Vine and many others)
- Polls options are displayed with Radio-Buttons + "*Vote*" button
- Custom Objects are displayed very basically using Compact Layouts field specifications
- And so..

Now, is there a way to modify this default behaviour ?

For core/standards objects, it may be restricted. I can understand that.
But it would be great to fully manage the rendition of custom objects (using VisualForce Page & CSS).

Do you have any idea ?

Regards,
Franck

Comment: There is a metadata of `FeedItem-Feed Item Layout.layout`.  Maybe you can edit that and use Ant to deploy it.